# main not exiting after reading from channel

Tags: go

I'm learning Go, but struggle to understand why my app doesn't exit properly. With the code snippet below I get the correct result, but main never exits after the last file has been read. As far as I know this is because it's an open channel somewhere, but I can't figure out why and how that is possible.

The gist of this app is to take an array of PDF-files and read out a certain string of it.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

type PDF struct {
    filename string
    code string
    error  error
}

func (p *PDF) GetCode() string {
    return p.code
}

func main() {
    jobs := make(chan PDF)
    results := make(chan PDF)

    for w := 0; w < 8; w++ {
        go worker(jobs, results)
    }

    // PDF files to read.
    pdfs := []string{"test.pdf", "test2.pdf", "test3.pdf"}

    for _, file := range pdfs {
        go func(file string) {
            jobs <- PDF{filename: file}
        }(file)
    }
    defer close(jobs)

    for i := range results {
        fmt.Printf("%s ", i.GetCode())
    }
}

func worker(jobs <-chan PDF, results chan<- PDF) {
    for file := range jobs {
        fmt.Printf("Processing %s\n", file.filename)
        code, err := outputPdfText(file.filename)
        results <- PDF{filename: file.filename, code: code, error: err}
    }
}

func outputPdfText(inputPath string) (string, error) {
    // Code that reads PDF and returns value
    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has deadlocks. A good way to wait until the processing has been done is to use `sync.WaitGroup`. Add 1 every time you add a job to the worker and then in the goroutine call `wg.done()` to signal the job has finished. When the job count is 0 on the waitgroup your code will exit properly. Here is an example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type PDF struct {
    filename string
    code     string
    error    error
}

func (p *PDF) GetCode() string {
    return p.code
}

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {

    jobs := make(chan PDF)
    results := make(chan PDF)

    for w := 0; w < 8; w++ {
        go worker(jobs, results)
    }

    // PDF files to read.
    pdfs := []string{"test.pdf", "test2.pdf", "test3.pdf"}

    defer func() { close(results) }()
    for _, file := range pdfs {
        wg.Add(1)
        jobs <- PDF{filename: file}
    }

    go func() {
        for i := range results {
            fmt.Printf("%s", i.GetCode())
        }
    }()
    wg.Wait()
    close(jobs)
}

func worker(jobs <-chan PDF, results chan<- PDF) {
    for file := range jobs {
        fmt.Printf("Processing %s\n", file.filename)
        code, err := outputPdfText(file.filename)
        results <- PDF{filename: file.filename, code: code, error: err}
        wg.Done()
    }
}

func outputPdfText(inputPath string) (string, error) {
    // Code that reads PDF and returns value
    return "", nil
}
```